# Edittext hint back and forth Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation

So I have an edittext that may or may not have a hint longer than the edittext. I was wondering 2 things

1. Can we check the size of the edittext hint to determine if it is larger or smaller
2. Is it possible to animate the hint inside the edittext to move back and forth on a timer

Comment: Have you researched this at all before posting?

Comment: You could just make the `EditText` multi-line in order to fit the whole hint.